# WordPress not getting 404 locally

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

Just creating a WP theme. I have a local domain set up using MAMP Pro. All works fine but when I try to test the 404 page instead of seeing the 404 the URL changes to https and I get thrown into a Google Search.

```
http://mff/blog/aaa which should throw a 404 turns into https and a google search opens replacing my theme.
```

I've tried deleting my htaccess, I've tried re-saving my permalink settings.

Any ideas? BTW Not tested on a live server.

Thanks Richard

Comment: Is your WordPress url `http://mff/blog`?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? Just noticed that you accepted my answer as the right one, though it wasn't the root of your problem at the time...

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question, but does your theme have a `404.php` file in it? I know that's probably painfully obvious, but I always like to start with the easy stuff...

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes it does have 404.php

Comment: Odd. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!

Comment: Just tried using the default permalinks and it still does the same. Also tried on a different WP install with default theme and still does the same so its obviously nothing to do with WP and all to do with my local machine set up with MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting you permalink settings to default. See if that gets you anywhere.

Also try this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/no-404-errors/
I know it is outdated, thought it was worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks. I could be wrong but I don't think the problem is down to wordpress per say, I'm sure if I uploaded to a live server it would work I was thinking it was perhaps more to do with the local environment. Ill try resetting the permalink setting to default though.